# How to populate a donut chart in highchart for two set of data in single chart with legend for one set of data and pointer for another set of data?

Tags: highcharts

I need to generate a donut chart as mentioned below. In this chart, the 'family share' is 100% of the chart and 'individual share' is 50% of chart. 'Your share' and 'Employer share' will be anything between 100%. I am looking for assistance to display family share and individual share pointed in the chart itself and, Your share and Employer share mentioned in the Legend.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Dhinesh, You can use multiple series to mock data labels. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6hjx2be8/ Are you looking for something like this?

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for. I have a question on 'y' property in family share and individual share data arrays. What does that represent? Also, what data in the code makes the chart  100%?

Comment: Family share is just created for data labels. It can have any y value because series with a single point will always have 360 degrees.